# Using more css property in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to put `.css()` for `:after` parametar. Ex. in jquery i need set different **background** color for *.dot* and for *.dot:after*

This is the css:

```
.dot {
position: relative;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;

border-radius: 50%;
}
.dot:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 3px;
left: 3px;
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
animation: pulse 2s infinite;
transform-origin: center center;
}

@keyframes pulse {
0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
25% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
100% {
    transform: scale(4.5);
    opacity: 0;
}
}
```

And here is jquery:

```
    function test_connection(){
    var target=$(".dot");
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/test_connection.php',
        cache:'false',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(a){
            inter=setTimeout(test_connection,15000);
            target.css({
                "background":"#77d804",
            }).html("<span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' data-original-title='Edit'></span>");
            connection=true;

        },


    });
}
```

With this i add just backogrund for **.dot**... but not work animation, cuz backgorund for **:after** is not set...

Someone idea how to set up background for both?

Thnaks

Comment: .dot ::after { 
   //Your code goes here
}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the styles of a CSS `before`/`after` pseudo element directly using JavaScript without appending a new `<style>` rule to the page or adding/removing classes on the parent element.

However, there's a good alternate solution for this particular case:

If you include the CSS rule `background: currentColor` on your `::after` element, you can alter its background color via JS simply by changing the `color:` property on the parent `.dot`.

Here's a working demo of how that would work:

(PS. I also modified your keyframe animation slightly so the dot fades in instead of abruptly appearing - take it or leave it!)

```css
.dot {
  position: relative;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  background: black;

  /* this will become the background of the ::after */
  color: green;
}

.dot::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  transform-origin: center center;
  
  /* this will inherit the parent's "color" */
  background: currentColor;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15%, 25% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(4.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dot"></div>
```